# If X is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular-material2, angular5

I keep getting this horrible error whenever I add a new material directive/component:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. **(By doing what, asshole?)**
2. If 'mat-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I have this in my main module:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatCheckboxModule, MatMenuModule, MatInput, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {RoutingModule, EmptyComponent} from './routing.module';
import {SharedModule} from './shared.module';
import {RouterModule, RouterLink} from '@angular/router';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppHeader,
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    EmptyComponent,
    ControlPanelComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    MatInputModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],

  exports: [
    RouterModule,
    RoutingModule,
    MatMenuModule
  ],

  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})


export class AppModule {
}
```

And this is a shared module, which I believe houses most dependencies:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule, Routes, RouterLink} from '@angular/router';
import {RoutingModule} from './routing.module';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({

  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    RoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
  ],

  declarations: [],

  exports: [
    RouterModule,
    RoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ]

})

export class SharedModule {
}
```

**what am I missing here? It's so unclear what I need to do to satisfy the dependencies needed.**

How do I verify that `mat-input` is part of this module??

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest you clean up your `AppModule`'s imports so you don't have modules being imported both in the shared module and the app module (this can cause issues, but from the error it doesn't seem to be the case). Second, does this error happen when importing? Or do you have a component like `<mat-input>` somewhere in a template?

Comment: somehow I get the feeling that `mat-input` is not an official directive/component

Comment: I saw it online somewhere in an example, but maybe it no longer exists, although the `MatInputModule` class seems to still exist, soo...dunno

Comment: In your app module try adding:  `schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` and import the constant from the `@angular/core`

Comment: Your code isn't clear. Please show you componet code, Your module declaration is seems to ok. May Something wrong in your component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a Material input with the following HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

Or simply:

```
<input matInput/>
```

There is no `<mat-input>` element in Material - the MatInputModule is imported to give you access to the `matInput` directive.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `<mat-input-container>`.